# How to auto-increment start with 500 index not 1 in mysql

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have requirement something like below.We need to insert auto-increment field start with 500 index.Now by default it is taken from index 1.
Have you any idea about this.

NOW :

```
Id  Name    Rollno  Class
1   ABC     111     10th
2   XYZ     112     10th
3   ASD     113     10th
4   QWE     114     10th
```

Want :

```
Id  Name    Rollno  Class
500 ABC     111     10th
501 XYZ     112     10th
502 ASD     113     10th
503 QWE     114     10th
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

following was yr table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`sonusindhu` (
          `SonuSindhuId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Rollno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `Class` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`SonuSindhuId`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=500 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

If you already created table then alter table syntax using following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`SonuSindhu` AUTO_INCREMENT=500;
```

Comment: But when I truncate this table it started index with 1

Comment: If you will truncate table then AUTO_INCREMENT value does not change. Means, in above definition i started AUTO_INCREMENT=500. After that i added 5 records. So, now AUTO_INCREMENT=505. If you truncate yr table and insert new record its ID will be 505.

Comment: this time you are wrong , i just checked its getting ID 1 not 505

Comment: In my case it's, 505 not 1

Comment: check yr table structure using SHOW CREATE TABLE `SonuSindhu`; what's AUTO_INCREMENT value?

Comment: OK. got yr problem.... If you use TRUNCATE `SonuSindhu` then AUTO_INCREMENT will reset to 0. Instead of TRUNCATE use delete from `SonuSindhu` query. That will remain AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: I want TRUNCATE because if we deleted all records then it will be start with 500

Comment: Ok found the solution we need to alter table after TRUNCATE 
`ALTER TABLE SonuSindhu AUTO_INCREMENT=500;`

Comment: @sonusindhu In that case you have to set AUTO_INCREMENT value to 500 ALTER TABLE `test`.`SonuSindhu` AUTO_INCREMENT=500;

Answer (score 1):

Set the default to 500 in phpmyadmin (unless you don't have access)

Or, use this mysql code.

`ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=500;`

Comment: I tried to set it 500 but getting error : #1067 - Invalid default value for 'id'

Comment: I am creating a table through phpmyadmin , but inserting data usign sql code

Answer (score 0):

1. on mysql
   ALTER TABLE Persons AUTO_INCREMENT=500

more details [auto increment](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)